# VS 2013 - Custom Control template gone?

Tags: wpf, templates, custom-controls

How are you supposed to create a new Custom Control with VS 2013? the template seems to have gone. I'm guessing that we're now expected to do this through Blend?

..the template was quite convenient as opposed to manually setting creating all the components

Comment: Did you have some sort of add-in?  My 2013 creates a custom control the way 2012 and 2010 did:  it gives you a cs file and a generic.xaml file.

Comment: Nope, but this is the free desktop version, I wonder if it has anything to do with that

Answer (score 0):

It's under the 'Web Forms' templates. Don't know why it doesn't show under Web, but typing "Server Control" into the search found it.